# C# Asynchronus TcpListener/Client. Keep-alive ping and reconnect

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcplistener

I'm rather new to tcp/ip so I hope my code's not an embarrassment. I have a tcp listener/client with 2 problems.

1. No keep alive ping so I won't know when to close the connection
2. If the connection is dropped, it won't smoothly reconnect

I am unsure how to implement these functions into my current codebase and am asking for best practices/ideas. Previous answers I've found all seem to be using either old information or different classes.
The listener's only required to connect to one client so that's fine.

TCPListener:

```
public async Task Start() {
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(_iPAddress, _listeningPort);
    tcpListener.Start(1);
    //Debug.Log("Listening on port " + _listeningPort);
    try {
        tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        clientConnected = true;
        //Debug.Log("Got connection request from " + tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        Debug.Log(exp.ToString());
    }
}

public async void GetData(Action<Ball> callback) {
    Ball ball;
    try {
        using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream)) {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            while (gameInPlay) {
                string dataFromClient = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

                ball = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ball>(dataFromClient);
                ball = BallConfiguration.AttachBallNumber(ball);
                if (registeredBalls.Any(regEpc => regEpc == ball.Epc)) {
                    callback(ball);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NullReferenceException e) {
        Debug.Log(e);
    } finally {
        tcpListener.Stop();
        clientConnected = false;
    }
}
```

TCPClient:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (!connectedToServer) {
                    ConnectClient(IPAddress.Loopback, 11000);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception : {0}", e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        } finally {
            if (tcpClient != null) {
                tcpClient.Close();
            }
            rfidReader.Stop();
            rfidReader.Disconnect();
        }
    }


private async static void ConnectClient(IPAddress ip, int port) {
        if (tcpClient != null) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect to Server...");
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
                connectedToServer = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Server");
            } catch (SocketException) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to server");
            } catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When using TcpClient the Socket is tcpClient.Client .  So set the socket options.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jdweng It is my understanding that specifying a keep alive in the Socket options will not actually tell me if the connection is still open or not.

Comment: I'm not sure.  The issue with TCP is when the Ethernet cable is disconnected the connection doesn't close without a Keep-Alive (other cases as well) .  A connection close is a signal (not a message) that is sent across the ethernet with an ACK returned.  So if you do not use keep-Alive then you never know if the connection is operational.  The keep-alive is usually sent every 5 to 15 seconds (a message with zero bytes) and the connection not operational is when you do not get the keep-alive usually for 30 seconds.

Comment: Hi Ian, just for learning purpose. How to connect async GetData method with connected client?